# How to gather information on a given theme using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, scrapy, bigdata

For example, I am interested in gathering daily information on a specific NBA player.

As far as i know Google do not allow to scraping it results. Does Google offers other possibilities for machine queries? Are they Python Packages to preform those queries?

Answer (score 1):

Most search engines don't want you scraping their results, but they do offer alternatives:

- Google Custom Search
- Google Alerts
- Bing API

There are also some services that sell access to what you want.  Off the top of my head, I know of:

- Brightplanet
- Webhose

(I'm not affiliated with any of these, but I have used all of them in the past.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am more intrested at the first part of your answer. Rather then services that cost money.